# Need to stop email notifications when giving permissions via Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm new to Google Apps Script and I need to stop email notifications when I give permissions. This is the code I have right now. But it sends an email notification every time.

```
function AddUsersToFolder() {
    // get folders (FolderIterator) by name, should probably be dynamic
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Work');

    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      // get the current folder from the iterator
      var folder = folders.next();
      // add viewer(s) and editor(s), should also be dynamic
      folder.addEditor('email@business.com');        
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enable the Advanced Drive API in Google App Script and use the Drive.Permissions.insert() method with the parameter sendNotificationEmails set to false to disable notifications.

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert).

Comment: I have looked at the documentation .... and I guess its over my head :( can you give me a example with user email address bob@mail.com and folder called work ?

Comment: @Jeremy use the Google APIs Explorer to test on your own and determine the needed inputs. It has an interactive resource that will be very helpful. If you have a specific issue with the code you come up with, ask [a new, specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).