# Setting permision on Team drive files via script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace, drive

I'm coding a simple apps scritp to set up permission on files located on a corporate teamdrive. Files and users to be enabled are  written into a google sheets document. The script reads each row for filename and user (identified by his/her email) and set the "viewer" permission. The basic script works fine but has the annoying feature to send email to each user it sets permission for. 
Here the working code:

```
    function simpleSetFilePermission_v1(filename, user_email){
      var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);

        while (files.hasNext()) {
          var file = files.next();
          if (file) {
            file.addViewer(user);
            return file;
          }
        }
    }
```

Looking for solution to avoid mail notification I run into various posts that suggest to enable advanced features and access the files on TeamDrive using the Advanced Google Services ([stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131692/need-to-stop-email-notifications-when-giving-permissions-via-google-apps-script)).
The problem is that APIS with apps script gsuite don't work.

```
    function simpleSetFilePermission_v2(filename, user_email){
      var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);

        while (files.hasNext()) {
          var file = files.next();
          if (file) {

            var _f_id = file.getId();

            Drive.Permissions.insert(
            {
              'role': 'reader',
              'type':'user',
              'value': user_email
            },
            _f_id,
            {
                'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
            });
            return file;
          }
        }
    }
```

In this function I've got errors "file not found" using *Drive.Permissions* functions. I've also tried others *Drive.** function with the same errros. Using the native *DriveApp.** functions everything works fine and the file ID are the same that run into errors with *Drive.** functions.

Is there some permission that must be set by the Admin (of course I've enabled the advanced services)?
Is there some limitations using the APIs together with the google app scripts? Thanks in advance

Guido

Comment: I just tested your simpleSetFilePermission_v2 and it worked fine, I didn't get any error, it set permissions correctly and it didn't send a notification email. Then I changed sendNotificationEmails to true and it worked as expected too. I'm using Appscript with Drive API service enabled.

Comment: hi Jescanellas,
   let me ask you some additional detail:
- how did you run the script? in my case the filename and user were picked up from a Google sheet with some code that I didn't report in the post
- did you use a personal Google drive or a teamdrive?
- I don't think it may influence the run, but what kind of file did you set the permission on?

thanks 

guido

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm posting an answer as it will be more clear than here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are getting the "file not found" error because you are listing the file without the "[includeItemsFromAllDrives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#try-it)" boolean. It's necessary until 2020, when it will become a default property of the `list` command. Otherwise it will not try to find the file inside the Team Drives.

Second, you need to add the "[supportsAllDrives](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)" boolean in your `insert` permissions call. This will be a default property in 2020 too.

Third, and more important, is that you can't degrade a user's permission in Team Drive for a certain file. For example, you can give Edit permissions to a Viewer, but you can't remove Edit permissions from a Contributor. You can find more information about permissions [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554?hl=en).